# Delete Records in Wcf Ria

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, enumeration

I use wcf ria in silverlight application. in the client side, i use following code to delete some records:

```
    var installments = context.Installments.Where(i => i.RequestId == selectedRequest.RequestId);
    foreach (var installment in installments)
    {
        context.Installments.Remove(installment);
    }
    context.SubmitChanges();
```

when run this code i have following error:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

how can i fix this problem?!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's happening because you're removing objects from the collection, while you're enumerating it.  The easiest way I've found to work around that is to add `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()` to the end of your enumeration line.  I.e.

```
var installments = context.Installments.Where(i => i.RequestId == selectedRequest.RequestId).ToArray();
```

This will give you an enumeration that is "detached" from the original collection.

Hope this helps.
Nate